# Calculating data used based on SELECT statement in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a DB that has two large tables that store some data with a DATETIME column. I found some queries that can display the total memory that the table takes but I wanted to take it one step further. I want to see how much data is stored in the table in one day.
For example, we have table T1 with columns TimeStamp, var1, var2, var3, ......etc.
I want to select the data for a specific date range and calculate the amount of data storage based on the data selected. Is this even possible?  I can't find anything on it.

Select * from T1
where TimeStamp > date1 and TimeStamp < date2

Comment: If you know the total memory used, I'd use the daily row count/total rows to get an estimate of the memory used in a day.

Comment: Insert the data for one day into another table (with identical schema, including indexes), then see what the size of that table is?

Comment: You could look into calculating the bytes used by each data type and adding the data lengths for each column/data type/datalength/null bitmap etc or probably easier to do as [other]Stu suggests - especially if you use row or page compression.

Comment: If these are very large tables, your DBA might have them partitioned by date already so you could get the size of one of the partitions (and then apply @BilltheLizard's suggestion if the partitions aren't exactly the timeframe you want). Of course, this is only different than using the total storage if the usage patterns of the table change over time.